# Matlab: What is the most efficient way to add zero rows (or column) to a sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have an `N x N` sparse matrix. Take for example `A = speye(N)`.
My general question is: what is the most efficient way to add zero rows (or column) to a sparse matrix?

Adding `jj` columns on the right side of the matrix and/or adding `ii` rows at the bottom of the matrix simply changes the size of the sparse matrix. So in code this would be

```
    N=2;
    A=speye(N);
    [rows,cols,vals] = find(A);
    % Add ii = 3 zero rows at the bottom
    % and jj = 2 zero columns at the left of A
    ii = 3; jj=2;
    B = sparse(rows,cols,vals,N+ii,N+jj);
```

Adding columns on the left and at the top, also changes the indices.

```
    N=2;
    A=speye(N);
    [rows,cols,vals] = find(A);
    % Add ii = 3 zero rows at the top
    % and jj = 2 zero columns at the right of A
    ii = 3; jj=2;
    B = sparse(rows+ii,cols+jj,vals,N+ii,N+jj);
```

Is there a more efficient way, for either of the two cases? For example, can I skip somehow finding the non-zero elements of `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a column as you would with a standard matrix

```
% Create a sparse matrix
A = speye(3);

% Add a column of zeros to the end
A(:, end+1) = 0;
```

Note that `find` will still only return the 2 non-zero values, but `size(A)=[2,3]`, i.e we've successfully added a column.

---

Variants:

```
% Still adding a column on the right, by concatenating with another sparse matrix. 
% However: this is less memory efficient with A on the right hand side
A = [A, sparse(3,1)];

% Adding column on the left
A = [sparse(3,1), A];         % comma is equivalent of 'horzcat'
% Adding a row on the top
A = [sparse(1,size(A,2)); A]; % semi-colon is equivalent of 'vertcat'
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks. So simple... didn't think of it... but this is only more efficient for the first part is it?

Comment: No worries, I've just edited to include a second option which is potentially more flexible if you're not just adding a zeros column.

Comment: So, yes, it seems to be faster. It seems using the full constructor of sparse is more efficient. 
Setting: `N= 2; ii = 3; jj = 2; A = speye(N);`
Code: `B = [sparse([],[],[],ii,size(A)+jj;[sparse([],[],[],size(A),jj),A]];`